# Realm lexical or preprocessor 'RLMAccessor.h' file not found Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

The error occurred when i updated pod
here is my pod file content

```
pod 'Realm', '~> 0.92.3'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'
pod 'ComponentKit', '~> 0.11'
target 'Plugd' do
end
target 'PlugdTests' do
pod 'Realm/Headers'
end
```

Comment: Can you try deleting `~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Realm` and `Pods/Realm` and installing again?

Answer (score 0):

Update 0.92.3 it's pretty big. Check the [installation](http://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/) steps again.